# Office 365 API Outlook Paging not working

Tags: c#, linq, outlook, office365

I'm using the Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices to consume the office 365 outlook web service.

I'm trying to query the user's inbox, with a paging support. Like this:

```
var query = from t in outlookServicesClient.Me.Folders.GetById("Inbox").Messages
            select t;

var mailResults = await query
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.DateTimeReceived)
            .Skip((pageNo - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

Supposing that pageSize = 10, and the user has 10 messages in his inbox, the property mailResults.MorePagesAvailable returns True, what is incorrect, it should return False.

It only happens when the pageSize is equal to the number of messages in the user's inbox. For example, if the user has 9 messages in his inbox, the property returns False.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Just as a sanity check - when you pass pageSize = 10, what is the value of pageNo? I think it could be a problem with the values passed to `Skip()` and `Take()`

Comment: the value of pageNo is equals to 1. (pageNo -1) * pageSize -> (1 - 1) * 10 = 0 * 10 = 0.

Comment: Try changing the code to 

`var mailResults = await (from i in outlookClient.Me.Folders.GetById("Inbox").Messages
                                     orderby i.DateTimeReceived descending
                                     select i).Skip((pageNo - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ExecuteAsync();`

It appears that you are pulling all the email from the inbox and then applying pagination.  Probably that could be causing this flag to be set to True.

Comment: I tried your code, but the problem still remains... :(

Comment: I found the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Create pagination in new messed up Outlook:

Click on the first email want then scroll
Down to whatever range you want.
Hold down shift + alt and right click.
This sets a range / page of your choice.